# Unable to deploy the solution using Release Management

Tags: deployment, release-management, ms-release-management

I want to implement the auto deployment functionality in my project using Release Management Tool. But it fails when the XCopy component tries to access the drop location to copy it to the destination server location, with the error "\servername\Drive\Path)"(Drop Location) does not exist or the deploy user doesn't have access to the it".

Things checked:

1. Configured the user to be a Service User on the RM using Deployment Agent tool.
2. Check for the drop path and found correct, can be browsed also.
3. Drop folder has the Service user accessibility with "Full Control" permission.

What I am missing here?

I also tried to used Windows Os -> Copy Files Or Folder component just to test the other way around, by hard coding the build definition path generated earlier and tried to trigger the RM. This time I got "Invalid Drive Specification error" in the logs.

Comment: Just want to confirm that you have definitely created a component from Configure Apps > Components.

Comment: @GrahamSmith: yes I have created the component with "Build Externally" radio box selected.

Comment: Sorry to have to ask, but are you building externally then? You aren't using a TFS build definition?

Comment: @GrahamSmith: I am using a TFS Build Def, but i am creating it on say Dev server and trying to deploy it on Test server. My RM is installed on Dev server in my case.

Comment: and one more doubt error message mentioned 'deploy user', so correct me if I am wrong- the deploy user will be the user whose account we have configured in the Deployment Agent tool and is the service user for our RM server..??

Comment: I am concerned here that the TFS/RM infrastructure is being confused with the server infrastructure that comprises the different stages of the deployment pipeline. Take a look at my blog post series to see how all this should be set up: http://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-tfs

Comment: What is the credential with which Deployment Agent service is running? This credential should have access to drop location. Also, make sure that you are able to access drop from deployment agent machine with this credential.

Comment: I've seen this when everything was set up correctly. The issue I ran into was that for some reason the deployer agent was not being served the correct share path, and it has somehow dropped an underscore from the middle of the path, when other underscores in the drop folder path were left intact.